# Using Safariservices swift how to code around the small black box

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate, safariservices

Using SFSafariViewController, works well but for some reason when I go to this webpage [knowitall.ch], it starts up by opening a zoomed view? with a small black box that I need to press to get the full webpage.

[image]

My code couldn't be simpler.

```
if let url = URL(string: url2U) {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

If I press the box I get the correct view, how to code around this so I open with the second view here? black box not required :)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That "zoomed view" is the Reader Mode. It shows up because you asked for it. Set `entersReaderIfAvailable` to `false` if you don't want it. Also, [`init(url:entersReaderIfAvailable:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/1621221-init) has been deprecated in iOS 11. You need to initialize it with a config object:

```
if let url = URL(string: url2U) {
    let vc: SFSafariViewController

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = false
        vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
    } else {
        vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
    }
    vc.delegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```